# Page refreshes immediately after draw (x3Dom)

Tags: javascript

I would like the "Add Cone" button to draw a cone, but it seems the code below refreshes the browser immediately after the cone is drawn. What I would like would be for the page to stay on the cone page after each button click, without the refresh. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    <script>
      function addCone() {
        var scene = document.getElementsByTagName("scene")[0];

        var cone = document.createElement("cone");
        var shape = document.createElement("shape");
        var appearance = document.createElement("appearance");
        var material = document.createElement("material");

        appearance.appendChild(material);
        shape.appendChild(appearance);
        shape.appendChild(cone);
        scene.appendChild(shape);
        return true;
      }
    </script>


    <div id="content">
      <form>
        <button onclick="addCone()">Add Cone</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'd return false if I were you.

Comment: Does the button click submit your form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="return addCone()">Add Cone</button>
```

**JS**

```
function addCone() {
    // ...    
    return false;
}
```